# Accessing .Net methods via JSInvokeable from HTML within Blazor WASM

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, azure-maps

We have integrated the Azure Maps Control into our blazor WASM app using the following library, so that we can get the benefit of interacting with Maps via C#:

https://github.com/arnaudleclerc/AzureMapsControl.Components

One of the options this component provides, is the ability to define a popup on mouseover of an element on the map using the HtmlMarkerPopup class. You provide html via the Content property of the HtmlMarkerPopup. If we want the popup to be interactive, we can call javascript inline, or reference javascript methods that are accessible to our index.html. But since the popup is written in HTML and NOT in razor, what I can't figure out how todo, is find a path to access .Net methods from any of the events raised within the popup. For example, if I wanted to add a button that onclick would do an http get, it's not clear how I would tap into the .net services layer that my other blazor components interact with. If I make a method JSInvokeable and call it from a javascript method that is called on the onclick of the button, it doesn't appear to be reaching it. I presume this is because the button is rendered as html, as opposed to being interpretted as razor. Is there any simple way to hook into a .Net method from this html popup? Or would I have to build a service within javascript (via something like axios) to compose http gets in these scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need to use `DotNet.invokeMethodAsync` and then have the name of the C# method you want to invoke: https://riptutorial.com/blazor/learn/100009/invoke-javascript-functions